# Not able to delete DocumentDB Since It is in incompatible-network

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I am not able to Delete or modify my Amazon DocumentDB database since it is in incompatible-network. It is in incompatible-network because I have deleted the VPC which is connected to that DocumentDB and I am not able to do anything with that Cluster, so how can I delete that?

[image: click here]

when I am trying to disable delete protection...I am getting the below error...

[image: click here]

even if I am trying to stop the cluster of Docdb I am getting the below error

[image: click here]

Comment: Please Edit your question to tell us exactly what steps you are doing and the _exact_ error message you are receiving.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein...Yes I have edited my question, Maybe it helps us to sort out the issue.

Comment: Sounds like something to ask AWS Support. You can subscribe to support, obtain their help, then unsubscribe from support.